# Captcha not showing on frontend login page

Tags: magento-1.9, login, rwd-theme, captcha

Captcha not showing on frontend login page. It works fine on register and forgot password section. I am using default template captcha module in **rwd template**. Following all the necessary changes. Guide me from this problem. I am using magento 1.9.2.2.

Comment: in case if it helps https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 0):

Login to backend Go to `system > configuration > customers > customer configuration > CAPTCHA` and select your website scope

Enable `CAPTCHA` on frontend - `Yes`

Select all forms into Form box

In Displaying Mode box select After number of attempts to login

**Set `Number of Unsuccessful Attempts to Login` = 0**

Save Config

Go to frontend and press Log in link to show the captcha form.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code for google invisible captcha. The spam emails are bypassing the old Magento inbuilt captcha. The following code will do the server side validation.

```
<?php class Addpeople_Validatecaptcha_Model_Customer_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer { 
public function validate()
{
    $errors = array();
    if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getFirstname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The first name cannot be empty.');
    }

    if (!Zend_Validate::is( trim($this->getLastname()) , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The last name cannot be empty.');
    }

    if (!Zend_Validate::is($this->getEmail(), 'EmailAddress')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Invalid email address "%s".', $this->getEmail());
    }

    $password = $this->getPassword();
    if (!$this->getId() && !Zend_Validate::is($password , 'NotEmpty')) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The password cannot be empty.');
    }
    if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array(self::MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH))) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')
            ->__('The minimum password length is %s', self::MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
    }
    if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array('max' => self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH))) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')
            ->__('Please enter a password with at most %s characters.', self::MAXIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
    }
    $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();
    if ($password != $confirmation) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please make sure your passwords match.');
    }

    $entityType = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('customer');
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'dob');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getDob())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The Date of Birth is required.');
    }
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'taxvat');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getTaxvat())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The TAX/VAT number is required.');
    }
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('customer/attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, 'gender');
    if ($attribute->getIsRequired() && '' == trim($this->getGender())) {
        $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Gender is required.');
    }

    if( Mage::getStoreConfig('validate_captcha/server_side_validation/enabled') ) {
        $errors = $this->validateCaptcha($errors);
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        return true;
    }
    return $errors;
}

private function validateCaptcha( $errors ) {

    /* additional reCAPTCHA validation */

    $action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
    if ( $action == 'createpost' ) {

        $captcha = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('g-recaptcha-response', 1);
        if ( $captcha == '' ) {

            $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Please check the reCAPTCHA field to continue.');
        } else {
            $params = array();
            $params['secret'] =  Mage::getStoreConfig('validate_captcha/server_side_validation/secret_key');
            $params['response'] = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('g-recaptcha-response', 1);
            $params['remoteip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            $params_string = http_build_query($params);
            $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?'.$params_string;

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $response = curl_exec( $ch );

            $result = json_decode( $response, true );
            if ( trim( $result['success'] ) != true ) {

                // This will be shown at the top of the registration page
                $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('reCAPTCHA unable to verify.');
            }
        }
    }
} }
```

Please refer my website for layout and config file details.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/invisible-recaptcha-register-form-magento/